# Quotation with source at right and a line break

Tags: memoir, quoting, quotation

Using memoir, I would like to add a source at right in the quotation below.  When I use no \ then it works, but the source is as wide as the quotation, which looks odd (at least to me). I tried adding \ but then the second line is set to fill the whole width of the page, which is not right.

I'd like to have it look something like this:

The acorn was a sort of reliquary in which the miraculous power of the idea was somehow enshrined.

```
                                                                   *Three Philosophical Poets* 
                                                                    George Santayana
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\title{Interesting words}
\author{Peter Flom}

\usepackage[marginpar]{todo}
%% A convenience command, for typesetting the
%% word and pronunciation

\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} (#2)\par}}

%\newcommand{\entry}[3]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} \normalsize(#2) (#3)\par}}


\newcommand{\sclabel}[1]{\normalfont\scshape #1}

%% Less spacing around lists
\firmlists


\begin{document}
    \entry{Reliquary}{Rhymes with relic stare me}
        \begin{flexlabelled}{sclabel}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.5em}{*}{\leftmargin}
         \item[Definition]
         A reliquary is a container for relics. Usually, these are holy relics associated with a religion, but the word reliquary can also be used more loosely - e.g. for a container for the bones of  deceased royalty.  One purpose of a reliquary is to be able to move the relics if the church or temple had to evacuate, as in times of war.
        \item[Etymology]
         From French \emph{reliquaire} which was first used in the 14th century. Not surprisingly, it shares its origin with relic, which originally meant ``body parts or other object from a holy person'' (see the Online Etymologoy Dictionary). Relic derives from Latin, \emph{reliquiae} which meant the remains of a martyr and from proto-IndoEuropean \emph{leikw-} meaning ``to leave''.
        \item[Usage]
         The meaning of relic has broadened with time; it is now used for any object of historical or sentimental interest.  The less common reliquary is going in the same direction.  For example, in New York City there is a museum called the City Reliquary, which displays artifacts from the history of the city, most of them not religious in any way. Reliquary is also the title of at least two novels.
         Example uses:
         \begin{quote}
         The acorn was a sort of reliquary in which the miraculous power of the idea was somehow enshrined.
           \sourceatright{\\ \emph{Three Philosophical Poets} \\ George Santayana}
         \end{quote}
         \item[Frequency]
         About 1 in 3.5 million words.
       \end{flexlabelled}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `\epigraph{<text>}{<source>}` command instead of the `quote` environment. For example:

```
\epigraph{%
         The acorn was a sort of reliquary in which the miraculous power of the 
         idea was somehow enshrined.}{%
         \textit{Three Philosophical Poets} \\ George Santayana}
```

Chapter 13 in the manual (`texdoc memoir`) provides full details of how you can adjust the result to your liking.